# How does this ETSFS algorithm Shifting work?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography

I am following the ETSFS enryption algorithm [here](https://thesai.org/Downloads/SpecialIssueNo8/Paper_7-Lightweight_Symmetric_Encryption_Algorithm_for_Secure_Database.pdf)

To give some context, ETSFS is an encryption algorithm encrypts a 4x4 data matrix by putting it through a series of data changing functions.

The step (with I/O) examples provided are quite clear in the before and after but the shifting step of the algorithm is somewhat confusing to me. (See Page 5/10) Here is the shifting I/O example from that page:

[image: Example of shifting]

*Please note that the allowed symbols in this algorithm is, in this order:*

`*   -   .   /   :   @   _`

`['*','-','.','/',':','@','_']`

*a-z and A-Z are labeled 0-25*

It says that the shifting is based on position of the element in the array. Unfortunately I cannot draw much information out of the given image. In the third line, it is not clear to me how `v` became `s` when I cannot see a correlation between `3` and `2`. Especially the last line in the image above where 4 becomes 2.

How does this shifting work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: In the link that you gave me, it explicitly states that a question about a software algorithm is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the information you're seeking (i.e. the content of the `arrayAlpha`, `arrayNumber` and `arraySymbol` arrays used in the shifting step) is simply not specified anywhere in [the paper you cite](https://thesai.org/Downloads/SpecialIssueNo8/Paper_7-Lightweight_Symmetric_Encryption_Algorithm_for_Secure_Database.pdf), nor do they appear to be derived from the key.  If you wanted to know what those arrays should contain, you'd have to contact the authors and ask.

In any case, I'd advise you not to bother.  The paper you cite does not appear to be written by professional cryptographers, and the algorithm it describes does not seem to be a secure encryption scheme in the modern sense.  It clearly does not provide [semantic security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security), much less [non-malleability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleability_(cryptography)). 
 Certainly, it would never have been published in any actual crypto conference.  The authors appear to have fallen into the common amateur cryptographer's trap of designing a cipher just complex enough that [they themselves can't think of a way to break it.](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html)  Also, they don't appear to be particularly experienced at breaking (or designing) ciphers.

I'd suggest using the time you would've spent working on this algorithm to instead familiarize yourself with the actual state of the art and best practices in modern cryptography.  For that, I'd recommend any decent introductory crypto book, such as Katz & Lindell's [*Introduction to Modern Cryptography*](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/imc.html) or Ferguson, Schneier & Kohno's [*Cryptography Engineering*](https://www.schneier.com/books/cryptography_engineering/).

Oh, and if you can avoid it, don't try to write your own low-level crypto code (except as a learning exercise).  Instead, find an existing reputable crypto library written and reviewed by professional cryptographers, such as [NaCl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaCl_(software)), and use it.

---

In fact, the "ETSFS" encryption scheme described in the paper looks pretty weak even for an amateur cipher.  As far as I can tell, the whole thing seems to amount to nothing more than a [polyalphabetic substitution cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyalphabetic_cipher) with 16 distinct key-dependent alphabets, combined with a key-independent(!) [transposition cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher).  (That's not how it's specified, but that's what it appears to work out to, if you trace out how each data character is affected by the iterated steps.)

As such, given that the transposition part of the cipher is fixed and publicly known, a few dozen 16-character [chosen plaintext / ciphertext pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack) (specifically, one for each character of the alphabet) encrypted with the same key should be sufficient to fully determine the substitution part, thus allowing decryption of any data encrypted with that particular key.  If a chosen-plaintext attack is not possible, a slightly larger sample of [known plaintext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) should be sufficient to recover *most* of the substitution table, if not all of it.

Also, given that there appears to be no mixing between the ciphertext letters, even if the transposition part was made key-dependent, breaking it would still only require 16 more chosen 16-character plaintext / ciphertext pairs.  (Exercise: Figure out a set of 16 plaintexts to choose so that, given the corresponding ciphertexts, you can fully determine the transposition part of the cipher without any prior knowledge of the substitution part.  Then figure out which additional plaintexts you need to also determine the substitution part.)